# On Conditional Probability defined as a random variable and its applications.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to get some **intuition** on conditional probability

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space and $\mathscr{G}\subset\mathscr{F}$ a $\sigma$-field contained in $\mathscr{F}$. We define the finite measure v on $\mathscr{G}$ by

$\text{v}(G)=P(A\cap G)$ for all $G\in\mathscr{G}$,

My doubts concerns the definition of conditional probabilities used by Patrick Billingsley (1995) in his textbook "Probability and Measure", which he denotes by $P[A\|\mathscr{G}]$, and defines by;

i) $P[A\|\mathscr{G}]$ being measurable $\mathscr{G}$,

ii) $\int_G P[A\|\mathscr{G}] \, dP=P(A\cap G):=\operatorname{v}(A\cap G)$ for all $G\in\mathscr{G}$.

**Questions**:

1. Say $A$ is independent from every $G \in \mathscr{G}$ then $P[A\|\mathscr{G}] = P(A)$ correct?
2. Say $\mathscr{G} = \{ \emptyset,\Omega \} $ then $P[A\|\mathscr{G}]= 1_A $? If this is true what is the probabilistic meaning behind this?
3. Could I have some examples, **with no independence relations** involved, where this definition is used and $P[A\|\mathscr{G}]$  is found explicitly?
4. Why does this definition allow us to do the following calculations:

Given $X_1,X_2 $ random variables s.t. $X_2 - X_1 \sim N(0,1)$ and s.t. $X_1 \sim N(0,1) $ is indipendent from $X_2 -X_1$ then

$$P(X_1 \le 0, X_2 \le 0) = \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} P(X_1 \le 0, X_2 -X_1 +X_1 \le 0 | X_1 = x_1 ) \, dP = (*)$$

I recognize that this equality is only the definition.

$$(*) = \int_{-\infty}^0 P(X_2 -X_1 +X_1 \le 0 | X_1 = x_1 ) \, dP = (*_1)$$

Here we start manipulating $P[A\|\mathscr{G}]$ and I **don't** understand why we may do this given the definition above.

$$ (*_1) =\int_{-\infty}^0 P(X_2 -X_1  \le -x_1 ) \, dP $$

Here we drop the conditioning completely and still I would hope for an explanation given the definition above.

In addition any link or reference to examples or relevant information is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Q2. If $\mathscr{G}$ is trivial, $1_A$ is not measurable w.r.t. it. For this case $P[A\|\mathscr{G}]= P(A)$. Moreover, this case is a subcase of Q1. Answer to Q1 is right.

Comment: Q3. Billingsley gives examples where $P[A || \mathcal{G}]$ is found explicitly. For instance, if $\mathcal{G}$ is generated by a finite measurable partition, then for almost all $\omega$ $$P[A || \mathcal{G}](\omega) = P(A | G(\omega)),$$ where $G(\omega)$ is the unique cell of the generating partition that contains $\omega$, and $P(A | G(\omega))$ is defined as usual by $$\frac{P(A \cap G(\omega))}{P(G(\omega))}$$ if $P(G(\omega))>0.$

Comment: And in Q4 in $(*_1)$ conditioning disappeared since $X_2-X_1$ is independent on $X_1$. This is again the work of Q1.

Comment: Re Q4, this follows from the fact that, for every event $A$ and every real valued random variable $X$, $$P(A)=E(P(A\mid X))=\int_\mathbb R P(A\mid X=x)dP_X(x)$$ where $P_X$ denotes the distribution of $X$. It might be worthwhile that in this context, **by definition**, $$P(A\mid X=x)=u(x)$$ where $u$ denotes any measurable function such that $$P(A\mid X)=u(X)\quad \text{almost surely}$$ Finally, to connect this with the rest of your post, note that, again by definition, $$P(A\mid X)=P(A\mid\mathcal G)\quad\text{with}\quad \mathcal G=\sigma(X)$$

Comment: Typo: It might be worthwhile *to mention* that...

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. @Did  where could I find a proof of the fact that $P(A)=E(P(A\mid X))=\int_\mathbb R P(A\mid X=x)dP_X(x)$?

Comment: @NCh  but what tells us formally that we can "substitute" $X_1$ with $x_1$?

Comment: @Did and I still don't understand why we can drop the $X_1 \le 0,$ from the joint distribution changing the upper limit of integration. Should this not require a proof that utilizes the given definition of conditional probability?

Comment: @aduh  I can't seem to prove your example using the definition, could you help me?

Comment: You are asking why, when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $P(Y\leqslant y\mid X)=P(Y\leqslant y)$. This, and the properties in my first comment which you are also asking about, are explained in every decent treatment of conditional expectations in the measure theoretical sense. For a very readable source, one can suggest Williams' small book *Probability with martingales*.

Comment: @did Why $P(Y\leqslant y\mid X)=P(Y\leqslant y)$ is clear to me thanks to the answer to Q1. In addition I own Williams book and there is a very nice treatment on conditional expectation, but as far as my understanding goes, there is no definition of conditional probability like that of Billingsley. I am trying to find proofs of the properties of the conditional probability as defined by Billingsley, I now have a doubt that I am misunderstanding and conditional probability as defined by Billingsley is the same thing as conditional expectation?

Comment: Conditional probability $P(A\mid\mathcal G)$ is by definition the conditional expectation $E(\mathbf 1_A\mid\mathcal G)$. Let me recommend to switch to Williams, more modern, easier to read, and quite complete and rigorous despite its congenial style.

Comment: @Monolite I'd be happy to try to help if you write something up and indicate where you are stuck. I don't think I will write up the entire proof for you though as it really is just a matter of checking the definition.